# Magento2 admin error

Tags: magento2

After I installed a theme in Magento 2 I have logged in to the admin panel that is showing this error:

> There has been an error processing your request.  Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1965137376".

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Start by going to var/report and reading the error in file 1965137376 paste the error into your question if you still need some help

Comment: Go to etc where you can find local.xml.sample remove sample from end of this file, you will able to print error on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy the static blocks in command line

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```